# How to calculate additive sum of all byte except checksum?

Tags: java, android

I have this hex string 09F7F8048400000FFF8E. In this string last two byte which is 8E, is the checksum.

I want to know that how to calculate additive sum of all byte except last two byte?

In short, if i will calculate additive sum of 048400000FFF, the answer should be 8E. Please help.

Comment: And where is the problem? With changing every two chars into byte? Or with summing? Did you at least try something?

Comment: I tried, i changed every char of data part to binary and added it and i got 3D not 8E.

Comment: simple math: 09+F7+F8+04+84+00+00+0F+FF=38E    ...=>...  38E & FF = **8E**...

Comment: Show us your code ... and we can explain what you did wrong.  But we ain't gonna writing it for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this in this way and it is working like wow :-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int checkSum = 0;
        byte [] bytes = hexStringToByteArray("09F7F8008100000FFF");

          for(byte b : bytes){
            checkSum += (0xff & b);
          }

          String checkSumHex = Integer.toHexString(checkSum & 0xFF);

          System.out.println("Checksum is: "+ checkSumHex);
    }

    private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```